# Error using split method in Codenameone

Tags: split, codenameone, build-error

I have created a new Codenameone project. It contains the following code:

```
String values = "one, two, tree";
String[] v = values.split(",");
```

When I build the project, I got this error:

```
location: variable definition of type String 
error: cannot find symbol
String[] v = values.split(",");
symbol:   method split(String)
```

However, if I take the sample project "MapsDemo" and use the split method, everything is ok.

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One supports a subset of Java 5 and `String.split()` isn't there. Its much harder to change the VM implementation code across all platforms than just add a portable library in the codename one package space. Its also harder to make all the edge cases 100% compatible and it makes the executable larger (you pay for String.split even if you don't use it!).

We have `StringUtils` and `StringTokenizer`, there is also a regex package in the [cn1lib](http://codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) section.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I will use 'StringUtils' instead. However, I would like to know ¿Why 'String.split()' DID work in your MapsDemo example. Could you please, tell me why?

Comment: Where in our maps demo do you see string split?

Comment: I did code a line (in your MapsDemo app) using String.split() and it worked. Why?

Comment: The simulator is based on Java SE so it has access to the full API internally. Its possible that something broke there since our demos are laid out in a non-standard way. However, if you would use this API when building to some of the platforms it will fail. It will not fail when building for Android or a Desktop target since on those platforms the API actually exists. But we block you from using it globally by default to enable WORA.

Comment: Thank you, Shai. You right. MapsDemo is very old and its build.xml allows to use several methods that will fail in the build process. May be it would be a good idea to update all demos. Thanks again. Kindly regards, Gustavo.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    ... ...
    String fruits = "apple:pear:grape";
    String delimiter = ":";
    StringTokenizer fruitsTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fruits, delimiter);
    while (fruitsTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String fruit = fruitsTokenizer.nextToken();
            //
            // Do here something you want...
            //
    }
```