# Codename One - String split

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a method that splits a string and continues with its logic after.

Now this method works in say a console or fx but using Codename One I get

```
error: cannot find symbol
for (String word : comment.split("\\s+"))
      symbol:   method split(String)
      location: variable comment of type String
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Now I know that Codename One is not the FULL JSK but more a restricted subset but I haven't found an alternative to splitting a string.

Should I create my own method or is there a way around to use another function?

Comment: Suppose you share the code of the method that uses `split()`it may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking to make their life easier here is a convenience method

```
public String[] split(String str)
{
    ArrayList<String> splitArray = new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer arr = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");//split by commas
    while(arr.hasMoreTokens())
        splitArray.add(arr.nextToken());
    return splitArray.toArray(new String[splitArray.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Warning: this only supports single char delimiters. If len(str)>1, it will only use the last character.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` is mentioned in [this article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) where we discuss the API's we don't support and why. There are several workarounds such as `StringUtils`, `StringTokenizer` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize for my mistake as the question was on SO but my research wasn't too well formed

[Error using split method in Codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875676/error-using-split-method-in-codenameone)

I used the apache.lang3 library to use the StringUtils to split my comment.